# Clicar no Span (ícone lixeira) para desencadear na minha li eventos de fadeOut e depois remove

Tags: javascript, span, opacity

Estou criando uma Todo List com vanilla js e esbarrei em um problema.
Quando clico no ícone da lixeira (dentro do meu span) não consigo deletar meu li.

Poderiam me apontar o caminho para que eu consiga fazer com javascript o efeito de fadeOut e logo em seguida remover o li da minha Todo list??

```js
var itens = document.getElementsByClassName("item")

for(var i = 0; i < itens.length; i++){
    itens[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
       console.log("Me deleta")
    });
};
```

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background: #50C9C3;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #96DEDA, #50C9C3);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #96DEDA, #50C9C3); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

h1{
    background: #2980b9;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li{
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #666;
}

li:nth-child(2n+1){
    background: #fff;
}

input{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #2980b9;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input:focus{
    background: white;
    border: 3px solid #2980b9;
    outline:none;
}

span{
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
    opacity: 0;
}

li:hover span{
    width: 40px;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.container{
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 360px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rbga(0,0,0,0.1);
    background: #f7f7f7;
}

.selecao{
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.fa-plus{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Todo List</title>
        
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>To-do List <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">
            <ul>  
                <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Estudar programação part I</li>
                <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Cuidar do Artur</li>
                <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Preparar almoço</li>
                <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Fazer exercícios de Sérvio</li>
                <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Estudar programação part II</li>
                <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Comer um chocolate</li>
                <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Lavar a louça</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/Todo2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Desde já agradeço !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar    `const li = this.closest('li');` para saber o `<li>` que queres remover e depois `li.parentElement.removeChild(li);` para remover. Isso vai mudar o DOM, se tens informação sobre o que é mostrado numa array por exemplo deves mudar lá também...

Para fazer o fadeout junto uma sugestão com uma animação, podes criar outras

```js
var itens = document.getElementsByClassName("item")

for (var i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
  itens[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    const li = this.closest('li');
    li.classList.add('deletar');
    setTimeout(() => li.parentElement.removeChild(li), 800);
  });
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #50C9C3;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #96DEDA, #50C9C3);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #96DEDA, #50C9C3);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

h1 {
  background: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #666;
}

li:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #fff;
}

input {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #2980b9;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input:focus {
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid #2980b9;
  outline: none;
}

span {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}

li:hover span {
  width: 40px;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.container {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 360px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rbga(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.selecao {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.fa-plus {
  float: right;
}

li {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .8s;
}

li.deletar {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Todo List</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>To-do List <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">
    <ul>
      <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Estudar programação part I</li>
      <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Cuidar do Artur</li>
      <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Preparar almoço</li>
      <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Fazer exercícios de Sérvio</li>
      <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Estudar programação part II</li>
      <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Comer um chocolate</li>
      <li><span class="item"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Lavar a louça</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/Todo2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Acho que ele  quer um efeito de **fadeout** no momento da exclusão do elemento.

Comment: @LeAndrade essa é a parte mais fácil e com mais variantes. Mas juntei uma sugestão, obrigado.

Comment: Dica: modificar o css adicionando animação no height, assim fica mais fluida a animação `li {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .8s;
  overflow:hidden;
}

li.deletar {
   height: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}`